# Replace Keyword Argument With Variable in Django Model Filtering

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-filters

I am performing filtering on a django model based on the data supplied by user in an input form. I don't want to hard-code values and so I would love to loop through the entire query parameters in `request.POST` and then filter by the key and value.

Here is a sample from my code

```py
class QueryView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        params = request.POST
        if params:
            for key in params:
                queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(key=params[key])
        return MyResponse
```

I can't get things to work as `key` must be a field in `MyModel`, is there a better way of achieving this same goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass them as dictionary:

```
queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(**{field_name: v1, another_field_name: v2})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can access the **POST** fields and values as `request.POST.items()` it would return a key value pair so you can do some thing like this

```
class QueryView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        params = request.POST
        if params:
            for key, value in params.items():
                # key is the field and value is it's value
                # now you can filter as you wish
                queryset = MyModel.objects.filter(key=value)
        return MyResponse
```

Comment: It such solution every iteration you will have a new queryset, you can add Q() and than use one queryset with ...filter(Q()).